# Dhtmlx bar chart text going out of parent div

Tags: javascript, html, dhtmlx

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="shared-learning-chart"></div>
```

**JS**

```
const sharedLearningBarChartConfig = {
            type: "xbar",
            css: "dhx_widget--bg_white dhx_widget--bordered shared-learning-chart",
            scales: {
                "bottom": {
                    title: "",
                },
                "left": {
                    text: "alert_type"
                }
            },
            series: [
                {
                    id: "A",
                    value: "record_count",
                    fill: "#394E79",
                    color: "none"
                }
            ],
            legend: {
                series: ["A"],
                form: "rect",
                valign: "top",
                halign: "right"
            }
        };
        const sharedLearningBarChart = new dhx.Chart("shared-learning-chart", sharedLearningBarChartConfig);
         const sharedLearningBarChartData = [
                    { alert_type: "Incident", "record_count": 25 },
                    { alert_type: "Near Miss", "record_count": 6 },
                    { alert_type: "High Risk Condition", "record_count": 5 },
                    { alert_type: "Policy Procedure", "record_count": 1 },
                ];
        sharedLearningBarChart.data.parse(sharedLearningBarChartData);
```

Here the text on the left is going out of div. Tried adding margin and padding but with no success. With this it is moving even with the border.

[image]

[Working Code Samples](https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/x8x3qt0g)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your report.
We'll try to find a solution in the future updates.
For now I can suggest you to rotate the scale text and change its padding,like:
https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/nnymqyrs
It may help to fit the titles.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better solution.
You can use the ["size"](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/suite/chart/api/chart_scales_config/#:%7E:text=the%20Y%20scale-,size,-(optional)%20sets%20the) property of the left scale to define the space reserved for the scale title.
Like:
https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/kvu3jrpp